# Getting CDATA content which is a slideshow

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML represented by this http://feeds.contenthub.aol.com/syndication/2.0/feed/53d27420b4075. I was able to access the title and link via my xsl which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <rss xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:twitter="http://api.twitter.com" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
            <channel>
                <author>
                    <xsl:text>Content-Feed-Pics</xsl:text>
                </author>
                <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item[position() &lt; 30]">
                    <item>
                        <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
                        <!--author><xsl:value-of select="dc:rss/dc:channel/dc:item/dc:creator"/></author-->
                       <!--icon>
                       <xsl:value-of select="concat(entities/media//media_url,':thumb')"/>                    
                       </icon-->


                        <link><xsl:value-of select="link"/></link>
                        <description><xsl:value-of select="description"/></description>
                        <pubDate><xsl:value-of select="pubDate"/></pubDate>
                    </item>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </channel>
        </rss>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
​
```

The two issues are to get the CDATA content for  node which is a slideshow enclosed within % %.
The second issue is there are certain nodes like  and  with namespaces. I tried adding dc: namespace to all the nodes in their path but the nodes were not getting accessed.

Kindly advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting CDATA you do not need to do anything special, it is just a way of escaping text in XML. Just get the value of the node, i.e. by doing `<xsl:value-of select="slideshow" />`, which will give you any data that is in there. Do note that the unescaped CDATA will be output this way. To use CDATA again in your output, add the `cdata-elements` attribute to `<xsl:output />` (not sure whether that was already available in XSLT 1.0 though).

To work with namespaces, you must also bind the namespace using `xmlns:xx`, where `xx` is the prefix. After that you can use that prefix in the XPath NameTest expressions.

To get an element in any namespace, use `*:elementname`.

Comment: if you look at the feed API http://feeds.contenthub.aol.com/syndication/2.0/feed/53d27420b4075 there is a description tag <description type="html">
<![CDATA[ %Slideshow-204761% ]]>
</description> Do you think the Slideshow itself is a content or its just a varible which can be used to reference the text using some kind of xsl.

Comment: @user3255127: I have no idea. The discription element can contain anything. That it is put in `CDATA` is not relevant, without it it would be exactly the same. A description is a description, usually. If it is not, someone is abusing a field for something that it is not meant to be used for. You should consult the owner of the feed to get any "higher" meaning of this.